# Cisco NX-OS licensing

Tags: cisco-nexus

I'm somewhat new to networking and I have been looking to pick up an older Nexus switch to learn more about it and the converged features.  I found a Nexus 3048 (for what I assume to be a reasonable price) on eBay however the seller states that there are no licences for it.

So the question is can I use a Nexus NX-OS switch without any licences? 
Is there a default base license that comes with them?

Thank you anyone that can help,
Greg

Comment: Yes, there's a built-in license you aren't supposed to be able to erase. Despite what Cisco want's you to believe, the doctrine of first sale applies, so the user license _is_ transferable. (if I buy X, I can turn around and resell X, exactly as I received it, and any right-to-use licenses go with it.)

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5):

In the [Cisco Nexus 3048 Switch Data Sheet](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-3000-series-switches/data_sheet_c78-685363.html) in table 3 you can see this:

[image]

(sorry for the image I cannot get the formatting right with a text paste)

So without specific license you get basic features with the system default. That is layer 2 features.

The switch may have been shipped with a base license, required for layer 3 (routing) features but you should ask the vendor for the result of a "show license" command.

Comment: Thank you for that, the seller showed a printout of the show license cmd and it returned nothing.  I was hoping to be able to do IVR, but if I don't have a license maybe I should go with a 5000 series and use my router as router on a stick

Comment: Have them try `show license usage` instead.